# Display the Filer Editor via code

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress

I have a gridControl in my form and I want when I click on a button to show me a Filter Editor as this :

[image]

There is already a feature in the GridControl to display this Filter Editor as you can see in this picture :
[image]

But I want to display it via code, and I don't know how to do it.
When I read the Filter Editor Document I found this :

> In code, the Filter Editor can be opened via the ColumnView.ShowFilterEditor method.

but when I tried to write it, it gives me this error :

> The name 'ColumnView' does not exist in the current context

Please, can someone tell me how can I display this Filer Editor via code ?

Answer (score 2):

The method is actually on the GridView itself, not the ColumnView.

```
  GridView gridView = yourGridControl.Views[0] as GridView;
  gridView.ShowFilterEditor(gridView.Columns[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks it worked, I also want to enable the Tree-Like and text-based filter editing style and i think this is the property which allows that :  `ColumnViewOptionsFilter.DefaultFilterEditorView`.  But i don't know how to use it